# Inner product and unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

$u_1 = (1, -1)'$ and $u_2 = (1, 1)'$ are two vector of $R^2$. Endow $R^2$ with an inner product such that $||u_1|| = 1$ and $||u_2|| = 1$.

Well, honestly, I don't completely understand what the problem asks. 
Endow $R^2$ with inner product? Then I tried the inner product of $u_1$ $u_2$.
So, $<u_1,u_2> $ $= (1,-1)*(1,1)=0$. Then two vectors are orthogonal. But I don't know to how to proceed. Do i have show that $||u_1|| = 1 $ and $||u_2|| = 1 $? if so, what theorem or formula should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean endow such that $||u_{1}|| = 1$ and $||u_{2}|| = 1$?

Comment: It wants you to find your own inner product where the conditions hold: not just apply the standard one.

Comment: @Jessica K Yes! I don't understand what it means.

Comment: @Johanna any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off the top of my head: try to define $\langle u, v \rangle = \frac{x_1x_2 + y_1y_2}{2}$. Is this an inner product? Does it satisfy the requirements?

Comment: I guess it is an inner product multiplied by 1/2. Do you requirements by $||u_1||$ = $1$ and $||u_2|| $ = $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inner product is a function of two vectors into $\Bbb R$ that satisfies certain properties.  You are asked to find a function $f((a,b),(c,d))$ that satisfies these.  You can't have $u_1=1$ because $u_1$ and $1$ are different kinds of things.  You can have $f(u_1,u_1)=1$, which is what you want.  The required linearity is a powerful constraint.  Express any two vectors in the basis of $u_1,u_2$ and you know their inner product.

Comment: So I have to find my own vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ that satisfy $||u_1||=1 $ and $||u_2|| =1? Thanks for your hints tho!

Comment: You are given the vectors in the problem statement. Now take any vector $(a,b)$, express it as a linear sum of $u_1,u_2$ and use linearity.

Comment: I guess I got it now! If I apply homogeneity in first slot, I will get $(au_1,u_1) = a(u_1,u_1)$ then find the value of a to satisfy $||u_1|| = 1$ and same method applies to $u_2$. Am i right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was completely lost before.